How can I prevent Dialogflow CX from rendering an object to a datetime?
I am building an agent in Dialogflow CX of which part of it consists of checking a datetime object if it's in the past or not.
THerefore, I use the system function IS_PAST_TIME.
When I set a parameter with dummy data { "year": 1989, "month": 5, "day": 16 } it works and I can set a conditional route,
but when I try to get an object within the parameter getOrders
{"orders":[{"cutOffTime":{"hours":16,"seconds":0,"minutes":"00","month":4,"nanos":0,"day":5,"year":2024},"deliveryDate":{"day":1,"month":4,"seconds":0,"nanos":0,"year":2024,"minutes":"00","hours":6},"orderId":6001101499,"totalToPay":"86.62"}]}
it renders the object as a date directly and it returns '$sys.func.IS_PAST_DATE("2024-04-05 16:00:00")'
I've tried several things with system functions TO_TEXT and TO_OBJECT but so far none of it worked.
What else can I try?

Hi @emmas90, there are many more details required on your issue including confidential data like the agent export file as well to investigate the issue further. So if you have a support plan please create a new GCP support case. Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the issue tracker describing your issue.

It is likely the date is rendered as string. Try the identity system function.
